# Evaluate this weird limit

Tags: limits

I start with the following family of functions:
$$x_1(t)=e^t, x_2(t)=e^{e^t}, x_3(t)=e^{e^{e^t}}, x_n(t) =...$$
I turn this into their corresponding ODE's:
$$\frac{dx_1}{dt}=:\psi_1(x)=x,$$
$$\psi_2(x)=x\cdot \ln(x),$$
$$\psi_3(x)=x\cdot \ln(x)\cdot \ln(\ln(x)),$$
$$\psi_n(x)=...$$

> **Now my question is, can we find the following function  $\Psi(x)$?**
>
> $$\Psi(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\psi_n(x)$$

I have the following first step:
$$\ln(\Psi(x))=\ln(\lim_{n \to \infty}\psi_n(x)) =\lim_{n\to\infty}(A(x)), $$
$$\text{where }A(x)=\ln(x)+\ln(\ln(x))+ \ln(\ln(\ln(x))) +...$$

Therefore, if $A(x)$ converges, so does $\Psi(x)$.

My intuition says that because the higher order logarithms come increasingly more negative, there is not limit.

Comment: For all values of $x$, the iterated logarithm quickly becomes undefined (in the reals) and so is $\Psi$.